# New Uber users must sign in Native App to update their payment methods?

Tags: uber-api

Do New Uber users should be signed in to Uber native app to create their payment method types (ex: cash)? I have got permission for all their scopes. I have used all their Api and this Payment method is making the New users to go from my app to Uber.

Is there any other methods where i can create payment method for other users from my app via Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you cannot create payment methods for these users. You can, however, poll their existing payment methods using: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/payment-methods-get

For them to add a new one or create one to start, they would need to install the Uber app.